# How to combine or call another class depending on a Yes or No button/Joptionpane

Tags: java, button, call, inner-classes

I have 2 separate classes.  One is a magic 8 ball, the other is a Wav player that plays the Interstellar song.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;



public class Magic8Ball {

private final static ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/BuckminsterFuller.jpg");
private final static SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
private final static String wisdom[] = {
        "Not Synergistically feasible",
        "It is geometrically analytical",
        "Your question does not follow General Semantics, hazy, try again",
        "Yes - Sustainable",
        "No, energetically inefficient",
        "Maybe a Dymaxion process.  Technology not up to date.",
        "Your question is negatively Entropic.",
        "Everyone is born a genius, but the process of living de-geniuses them.",
        "Humanity is acquiring all the right technology for all the wrong reasons.",
        "We are called to be architects of the future, not its victims",};


public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean askQ = true;

    while (askQ) {
        String question = getUserQ();
        String randomWisdom = getRandomWisdom();

        showWisdom(question, randomWisdom);

        askQ = userWantsToAskAnotherQ();
    }


}

private static String getUserQ() {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Ask a question that has to do with the structural integrity of earth:",
            "Only Engineers, Scientists and Architects allowed",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

private static String getRandomWisdom() {
    return wisdom[rand.nextInt(wisdom.length)];
}

private static void showWisdom(String question, String randomWisdom) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, question + "\n" + randomWisdom, 
            "Buckminster's Magic-8 Ball has responded.", 
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, image);
}

private static boolean userWantsToAskAnotherQ() {
    return 0 == JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Abort Mission or Dock "
            + "while Hearing" + "\n" + "No Time for Caution? by Hans Zimmer", 
            "Would you like to stay on spaceship earth or abandon ship?", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 0, image);
}

}
```

So as you can see at the end of the Class the option is to abort mission or dock while hearing Hans Zimmer No time for caution.  So if the user hits Yes, how can i have it active or call this class that i have for the interstellar song:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class WavPlayer extends JFrame { 
JButton btn = new JButton("Play No Time For Caution");
File wavFile;
URL defaultSound;
public static Clip clip;
public static AudioInputStream audioInputStream;

public WavPlayer(String url) {
    try {
        setSize(300, 100);
        setLocation(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        defaultSound = new URL (url);

        jp.add(btn);

        getContentPane().add(jp);
        pack();

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {             
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play();
            }
        });
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WavPlayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void play() {
    try {
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultSound);

        try {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.loop(20000);
            clip.start();

        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
    }
}

public void stop() {
    clip.stop();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    WavPlayer t = new WavPlayer("file:C:/Users/borjax01/Desktop/Netbeans/JavaApplication/music/Interstellar.wav");
    t.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Edit:  I already combined these 2 classes by refactoring and moving one class into the other.  What i want done is that i want the 8ball class to call upon the WavPlayer class when at the end of the 8ball class, when the user gets prompted to play again, and they hit "yes" to activate the wavplayer class.....

Answer (score 0):

What error did you get? "Inner classes cannot have static declarations" perhaps?

You can try another approach. Instead of nesting the wav player class, insert if after the Magic8Ball class. Both classes can exist in the same file, but as you know, only one of them may be public.

Comment: Ok, so to do that, I just remove the word "public" from public class WavPlayer extends JFrame  ?

Comment: Actually i just learned how to combine by right clicking, moving it into the class.  But when i run this now it just says "which class do you want to run? 8ball or Wavplayer."  What i want 8ball to do is call upon the Wavplayer when the user chooses "Yes" at the end of the game.

Comment: The call to JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog returns an integer that matches the button pressed. You might try something like this:

Answer (score 0):

Now that both classes are present you might try something like this:

```
value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)
if (value == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    WavPlayer t = new WavPlayer("file:C:/Users/borjax01/Desktop/Netbeans/JavaApplication/music/Interstellar.wav");
    t.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: So i know i don't copy and paste that exactly as you wrote it.  So do i replace the word "value" with what i have in MY code such as return 0 == followed by what you wrote in your code?